# Continuous-time Markov chains - probability of leaving, and not returning to, a state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a continuous-time Markov chain $X_t=X(t)$ which is governed by the generator matrix $Q=(Q_{ij})$, where $\sum_{j} Q_{ij}=0$ and $Q_{jj}=-\sum_{i \neq j}Q_{ij}$.

I want to find the probability $p$ that $X$ is not in state $k$ at time $t_1$ AND that $X$ has only left state $k$ once, given that $X$ was in state $k$ at time $t_0$. More concisely,

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{t_1}\neq k \cap \text{ $X$ has not returned to $k$} \ | \ X_{t_0}=k).$$

I think this can be restated as

$$\int_{u=(t_0,t_1)} \mathbb{P}(X_{(t_0,u)} = k \ \cap \ X_{[u,t_1)} \neq k \ | \ X_{t_0}=k) \ du$$

for $t_0<u<t_1$, where $X_{(t_0,u)} = k$ is just a way to state that $X$ is in $k$ in the interval $(t_o, u)$.

I'm hoping a closed-form solution is possible. Can anyone help?

I'm ignoring the complement of the problem (either being in state $k$ at time $t_1$ OR not being in state $k$ at time $t_1$ but having re-entered it at least once since time $t_0$) because this also seems hard.

NOTE: A previous version of this question was incorrectly stated. It also included a partial solution which was incorrect. I've removed these.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something since it appears trivial. If we condition on $X$ not visiting $k$ before $t_1$ (and since this is a *continuous time* Markov chain), then the only way for $X$ to be in state $k$ at time $t_1$ is 1) $X$ jumps to state $k$ precisely at time $t_1$, which occurs with a probability of 0, or 2) $X$ never leaves $k$. Thus the probability of this occurring is just the probability that $X$ never jumps at all, which is easy to compute. Is there something I'm missing about the setup?

Thus I think the answer is just $$1 - P(X \text{ never jumps })$$

Comment: Thanks, @Kurt. 

Let $t_0<u<v<t_1$ and assume $X_{t_0}=k$. If $X$ leaves $k$ at $t=u$, returns to $k$ at $t=v$, and is still in $k$ at $t=t_1$, then $X_{t_1}=k$. 

In other words, $X$ *can* be in $k$ at time $t_1$ without meeting your two conditions (jump to $k$ at exactly $t_1$ OR never leave $k$), so your solution doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @Kurt, I've updated the question - it was stated incorrectly. I think you'd answered it as originally stated - Sorry!

Comment: I think the best approach is to create a new generator matrix, call it $\tilde{Q}$, where $k$ is an absorbing state. Then we can break down the probability . I will describe it a bit vaguely. Write down the probability in terms of jumping once to a state other than $k$ before time $t_1$, and then use $\tilde{Q}$ to compute the probability of avoiding $k$ after that. When you use $\tilde{Q}$, you can compute the probability of being in each state by computing $e^{\tilde{Q} t_1}p_0$, where $p_0$ is the probability of starting in each non-$k$ state after the first jump.

Comment: I think those are the pieces, but I'll leave it up to you to put it together. @wjchulme

Comment: I think you actually need to use $e^{\tilde{Q} (t-\tau)}$, where $\tau$ is the time of the first jump.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a closed-form solution, but I think with some more work you can get it there. Anyways, change the generator matrix $Q$ such that it has all zeros in row $k$, call this matrix $\tilde{Q}$. This changes state $k$ to an absorbing state. Then the answer is

$$1 - \int_0^{t_1} \left[e^{\tilde{Q}^T(t_1-\tau)}P_{k,\cdot}^T\right]_k \lambda_k e^{-\lambda_k \tau}\,d\tau$$

where $P_{k,\cdot}$ is the $k$th row of the transition probability matrix, and $\lambda_k = -Q_{kk}$. Also $[\cdot]_k$ refers to the $k$th element of the vector. I tested this out with some simulations and it works. Essentially we are integrating over all the possible times of the first jump, and then the stuff inside the square brackets is the probability of ending up in state $k$ at any point between the first jump and $t_1$. Thus the integral gives the probability of ending up in state $k$ at any point after the first jump, so we need to compute 1 minus that integral.

Comment: Thanks, @Kurt. I'm going to leave this unaccepted for now but once I check it over myself I'll accept, unless I can put together an answer in closed-form. Your responses have certainly helped me to clarify my thinking about this problem so either way I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: I tried getting it into a closed-form by writing down the exponential as a series, and then switching the order of the integral and the sum. The best I could do was rewrite the integral in terms of an incomplete gamma function, which wasn't much of an improvement. Maybe there's some nice simplification if you go further down that road though.